# authorizationGrantType cannot be null in Spring Security 5 OAuth Client and Spring Boot 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I followed the Spring Security 5.0 official reference documentation and sample codes [oauth2login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login) to setup OAuth2/OIDC authentication in my project, but it failed and I got the following exception when I booted up my application by `mvn spring-boot:run`.

```sh
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' 
    defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: 
    Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: 
    Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authorizationGrantType cannot be null
```

I was using the default configuration provided by Spring Boot and just added some basic dependencies into projects, such as `spring-security-config`, `spring-security-oauth2-client`, `spring-security-oauth2-jsoe` etc.

**Updated:**

**I've found the reason**, for custom OAuth2 providers, such as **Gitlab**,  I have to add **grant type**, **redirectUritemplate**, **scope**, **clientName** etc, but OpenID Connect specification has a configuration endpoint protocol, eg: https://gitlab.com/.well-known/openid-configuration , is there possible to make Spring Security read this info automatically?

**Update(5/15/2021):** in the latest Spring Security 5.4 and Spring Boot 2.4, the OpenId configuration(`.well-known/openid-configuration`) is discovered by default, for most oauth2/oidc authorization servers, configure a
`issuer_uri` is enough.

Answer (score 20):

use redirect-uri instead of redirect-uri-template if use SpringBoot v2.2.1 RELEASE

Comment: The same applied to version Spring boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE. Thanks!

Comment: same is applicable in 2.3.2

Answer (score 17):

To elaborate on [Arpeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59173235/1389817), the properties you need to include in your `application.yaml` to resolve the original error are as shown below, in this case for Azure AD (note this ONLY works with Spring Security 5, NOT Spring Security OAuth2 2.x whose functionality is [being merged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix) directly into Spring Security 5):

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          microsoft:
            client-id: a935ba7b-6aa4-4b0c-9e84-04f9acaa477b
            client-secret: redacted
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope: User.Read
            client-name: Microsoft
            client-alias: microsoft
        provider:
          microsoft:
            authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
```

Comment: I understood this, but I 'v read the docs, it said some properties should have default values, eg `redirect-uri-template`, but it did not apply to cusotm config.

Comment: I had the same experience, but I am posting here so others know exactly what properties need to be filled out in full

Comment: it looks like you can use issuer-uri instead of authorization-uri, token-uri, jwk-set-uri, and user-info-uri in certain cases. I created a custom okta provider/registration (but named it test so that spring wouldn't auto detect a bunch of crap for me) and issuer-uri actually worked for me by itself.

Jwk-set-uri has more of a potential need to be set independent of issuer-uri sometimes, though i haven't quite wrapped my head around that portion of when and why.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-jwkseturi

Answer (score 6):

redirect-uri-template -> redirect-uri
it works SpringBoot 2.2.0.RELEASE

but it works spring 2.1.x with redirect-uri-template

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following property to my `application.properties`:

`spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.authorization_grant_type=authorization_code`

After which it started complaining that "Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oidcUserService'"

At which point I had to add the following to the `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers()
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
        .includeSubDomains(includeSubDomains)
        .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);
    http.requestCache()
        .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("Our permitted end points")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .oidcUserService(oidcUserService());
  }

  private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
    final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();

    return userRequest -> {
      OidcUser oidcUser = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);

      Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

      oidcUser =
          new DefaultOidcUser(mappedAuthorities, oidcUser.getIdToken(), oidcUser.getUserInfo());

      return oidcUser;
    };
  }
```

Then is started working...
Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html

Answer (score -1):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add this dependency in your pom and check

Comment: This is for the legacy Spring Secuirty 4.x and Spring Security Oauh(deprecated).