# Spring 5 Security OAuth2 Login Redirect Loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to work with Spotify Web API, but I'm having trouble with Spring Security Configuration. Here are my security dependencies:

```groovy
 /* springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE' */
implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client"
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.1.6.RELEASE'
implementation "org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.7.RELEASE"
```

And here's my security in my `application.yml` file:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          spotify:
            provider: spotify-provider
            client-id: <client-id>
            client-secret: <client-secret>
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/
            scope: <comma delimited scopes>
        provider:
          spotify-provider:
            authorization-uri: https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
            token-uri: https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
            user-info-uri: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me
```

My issue is that after I login and get redirected back to my application, it gets stuck on the URL `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/spotify` with the error

> localhost redirected you too many times.

Here's what my java security configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class SpotifySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without explicitly specifying 'redirect-uri' in the client registration?

Comment: Without the `redirect-uri` I'll get an exception: `IllegalArgumentException: redirectUriTemplate cannot be empty`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Redirect Loop was because the `/oauth2/authorization/` endpoint was secured, thus it was triggering going back to the Web API for an access token.

I've updated my configuration to this:

```
@Configuration
public class SpotifySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home", "/login**","/callback/", "/webjars/**", "/error**", "/oauth2/authorization/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
  }
}
```

The second issue was that the `redirect-uri` is the URI that the Web API will send the access token to Spring to be used to get the refresh token. I thought it was for a successful login. Spring already has an implementation for handling refresh tokens, but I did not know what endpoint it should use. For some reason, the redirect-uri cannot be blank, there is no default, I would get this error:

> IllegalArgumentException: redirectUriTemplate cannot be empty

To use Spring's refresh token implementation I needed to set the redirect-uri to this:

```
redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
```

`redirect-uri-template` is an alias for `redirect-uri` (they're the same variable).

I found the `redirect-uri` in another stackoverflow post:

[authorizationGrantType cannot be null in Spring Security 5 OAuth Client and Spring Boot 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315552/authorizationgranttype-cannot-be-null-in-spring-security-5-oauth-client-and-spri)

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I would make a slight correction to your answer: `redirect-uri` is where the identity provider, Spotify in your case, will send the authorization code, which will be exchanged by Spring for an access token.

Comment: This answer is only half-true. The `/oauth2/authorization/**` endpoint should not necessary be `permitAll()`. Unsecuring this URL is unnecessary. Filter, that processes this URL, triggers earlier anyway, so, authorization rules don't affect it. "The second issue" part is actually what caused this problem. Redirect URL should be set and it should be set to something, that matches `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` pattern, that by default is `/login/oauth2/code/*`. When it was set to `http://localhost:8080/` (that is secured), then `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` didn't catch the request.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation :

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SpotifySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe `@EnableOAuth2Sso` is the old way of doing OAuth2. Anyways, I've tried adding it, but then I get redirect loop on `http://localhost:8080/login`.

Comment: Can you share the doc link which marks EnableOAuth2Sso as deprecated. I believe it is the correct approach with Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE and Spring security 5.2.1

Comment: @SivaSenthil George is right, I read the same, on Stackoverflow saying  `@EnableOAuth2Sso` is older way doing, there is no such doc as such Donno