# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

can someone help me? these are the errors I get when I run my application spring boot

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.progettopiattaforme.ProgettopiattaformeApplication.main(ProgettopiattaformeApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:408) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1525) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1265) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1525) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1265) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
    at java.base/sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:192) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1181) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.lambda$oidc$0(ClientRegistrations.java:147) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.getBuilder(ClientRegistrations.java:195) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.fromIssuerLocation(ClientRegistrations.java:138) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getBuilderFromIssuerIfPossible(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistration(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.lambda$getClientRegistrations$0(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1336) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.clientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 75 common frames omitted here
```

this is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>progettopiattaforme</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>progettopiattaforme</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11.0.9</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is my securityConfiguration

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

                .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/images/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                )
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://$dev-1724846.okta.com/oauth2/default
okta.oauth2.client-id=0oaj334aI5JtaHJZF5d5
okta.oauth2.client-secret=PKCE
okta.oauth2.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: can you attach files related to security configuration ?

Comment: where is your oauth2 client configuration？ In most case, it will be in application.yml or application.properties.It starts with as spring.security.oauth2.client. you should config it.

Comment: which configuration are you talking about? i have added my application.properties if it can be useful

Comment: @hirarqi @jacky-neo  this is my application.properties, can i help me?                                                 `okta.oauth2.issuer=https://dev-1724846.okta.com/oauth2/default
okta.oauth2.client-id=0oaj334aI5JtaHJZF5d5
okta.oauth2.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/ `

Comment: @Ramona - where you able to solve this? I get the exact same error running in another setup than localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [grant type](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/AuthorizationGrantType.html) into the `application.properties` as:

```
okta.oauth2.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
```

As in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63024547/9752394).